# Vue store slot data in parent component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm building a component which takes in multiple input fields using a slot, when the user submit's the form inside the parent component, I want to output the values of all the inputs.

**index.html**

```html
<filter-form>
    <input type="text" name="email" :value="form.email" />
</filter-form>
```

**FilterForm.vue**

```js
<template>
  <div>
    <form
      @submit.prevent="onSubmit"
    >
      <slot />
      <div>
        <button>
          Submit
        </button>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      form: {
        email: 'test@email.com'
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

As you can see I'm referencing "form.email" inside index.html, which should populate the input with the data in the FilterForm component, however that's throwing this error

`Property or method "form" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render`

Which makes sense since the form data isn't available in the index.html file.

#### How can I use this system so that the data for the form is kept in the FilterForm component, but I can add any numbe of form inputs to the index.html file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vue has a feature called [Scoped Slots](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html#Scoped-Slots) which might solve your problem.

```html
<filter-form>
  <template v-slot='slotProps'>
    <input :value='slotProps.form.email' />
  </template>
</filter-form>
```

and

```html
<div>
  <form @submit.prevent=''>
    <slot :form='form'/>
      <div>
        <button>Submit</button>
      </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/xy5rnb96/)

Answer (score 0):

As @User 28 mentioned, you can take advantage of slots and scoped-slots to get this to work with an arbitrary number of fields like so:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <FormWrapper :names="['name', 'country']" @submit="process($event)">
      <template #default="{ form }">
        <input name="name" type="text" v-model="form.name">
        <input name="country" type="text" v-model="form.country">
      </template>
    </FormWrapper>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import FormWrapper from "./components/FormWrapper";

export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {
    FormWrapper
  },
  methods: {
    process(values) {
      console.log(values);
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Here, `FormWrapper` can nest arbitrary input fields. Some key points:

- You need to provide `names` prop with some unique IDs for fields you care about.
- When form inside `FormWrapper` is submitted, a `submit` event will be triggered with the values sent as an object.
- Also note that we pass data for our slots in a `form` object and bind it to our inputs via `v-model`.

Here is the `FormWrapper` component:

```
<template>
  <div class="form-wrapper">
    <slot :form="form"></slot>
    <div class="controls">
      <button @click="submit()">Submit</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    names: Array
  },

  data() {
    return {
      form: {}
    };
  },

  created() {
    for (const name of this.names) {
      this.$set(this.form, name, "");
    }
  },

  methods: {
    submit() {
      this.$emit("submit", this.form);
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

You can check https://codesandbox.io/s/so-form-wrapper-yxz0i for a working example.